# WPF: change listview item background/foreground on selection or mouseover

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface

I have a listview in my WPF program, and I wanted to change the style of the list view items when I hover my mouse over them or when they're selected

This is the code I currently use:

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#1A1A1A"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                </Trigger>

                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#1A1A1A"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

problem is, that it only changes the border thickness or the font weight
The background and the foreground doesn't change at all

and I can't find any thing that helps online

List view Item on hover:
[image: List view Item on hover]

List view Item when selected:
[image: List view Item when selected]

I've tried using this approach - using my own color values ofc

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black"/>                      
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then I've also tried disabling focusable - which removes the selection highlight, but also removes the functionality which isn't supposed to happen

Comment: The default Item Template is determined by the current OS theme. In Win 7 and 10 they are different. As far as I remember, the changes happened with Win 8.1. In Win 7, DynamicResource could be used in themes, so keys were often redefined at runtime. On Win 10, only StatucResource is allowed. Which actually causes the resources used to be template constants. Therefore, to solve your question, you will need to completely override the ListViewItem Template.

Comment: Another way is to set colors not to the ListBoxItem, but to its contents using the DataTemplate in the ItemTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

This did what I wanted to do

Removed the default hover/selected effect so that I could use setters to make my own effect

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```